# Laravel custom validation message

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm using laravel 5.4 to make a custom form validation. But why is the custom error message isn't displayed?

```
   Validator::extend('myCustomeValidator', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        //some code here
        return false;
    });

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'myField' => 'myCustomeValidator',
    ]);
```

and added the following to the file : `ressources\lang\en\validation.php` as the documentation advises:

```
    'custom' => [
        'myField' => [
            'myCustomeValidator' => 'You made an error.',
        ],
    ],
```

The error is correctly triggered but instead of my custom error message, I get this:

> validation.my_custome_validator

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **snake-cased** name of your custom validation rule. The following should the trick:

```
'custom' => [
    'myField' => [
        'my_custome_validator' => 'You made an error.',
    ],
],
```

Comment: yes, it works. It doesn't even accept 1 capital letter.